# Do Dragonborn get tails/wings?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonborn

I have heard along the grapevine that at some point, Dragonborn can get wings and/or a tail. But I haven't been able to find anything on it. I have looked through the Player's Handbook, and I couldn't find anything in there about it.

So do Dragonborn get tails or wings at any point? I know they don't start with any, but as I said previously, I heard they could. Does it depend on the ancestry as well? (I.e. Blue Dragonborn only get tails, Black only get wings etc).

This is the inspiration for this question. I'm unsure of where it came from, it may just be fan art, but I have seen similar images (perhaps by the same artist) that led me to believe that this may be canon.

[image: Dragonborn]

Comment: It may be worth noting that the art you see may be from previous editions, which may have had dragonborn with wings. Despite being a race in three editions in a row, the dragonborn have been rather wildly different each time (within the bounds of “dragon-ish humanoid race” anyway).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No. You're probably thinking of the Dragon Wings feature from the Sorcerer's Draconic Bloodline archetype.

> Dragonborn look very much like dragons standing erect in humanoid form, though they lack wings or a tail. *- Player's Handbook, pg. 32*

Answer (score 10):

Justin's answer is correct by the core rules, however, the *[Feats for Races](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/feats-races)* Unearthed Arcana, released 2017-04-24, has the *Dragon Wings* Feat (pg2), which is Dragonborn-only and gives the character wings.
Mechanically, this grants a 20' fly speed while not in heavy armour.

Note that Unearthed Arcana additions are playtest material and thus not guarunteed to be balanced. As always, ask your DM first and be prepared for a 'no'.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Xanathar's Guide to Everything was released after this material but did not include it (but did include other racial feats for the Dragonborn). One could interpret this to mean that they "dropped" this feat.